# How to make the label appear in gantt chart even if the area is small

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate, foundry-workshop

Ref this screenshot of Gantt Chart in Slate, when the bar is small the label 1 is not visible,
How to make the label small dynamically so that it fits within the bar area instead of becoming blank value.
[image]
css code or html code to make the label 1 appear in the available space

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in highlighting that the whole label element is removed from the dom when the chart is too small. This is due to how the underlying plotting library, [Plottable.js](http://plottablejs.org/), currently works + how it's used to implement the gantt chart in Slate (if interested, see [this file](https://github.com/palantir/plottable/blob/aaeb772923519d4b338f955b6b6f9431065a6bd6/src/plots/barPlot.ts#L582) for a decent entry point into the code). I don't see any way of solving the issue with the native Slate gantt chart apart from making it wider.

Here are some alternatives and workarounds:

1. Enable pan and zoom on the gantt chart so users can at least zoom in to see the label. See this gif for what that looks like: [image: zooming into the Slate gantt chart]
2. Load an external Javascript library for gantt charts and use Slate's [Code Sandbox](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/widgets-advanced/#code-sandbox) to use it in your application
3. Use Slate's HTML text widget and a Slate Function to generate HTML/CSS for a *static* gantt chart. This would essentially look like passing in your data to the function and generating an HTML string that is displayed in the HTML text widget. To get a basic gantt chart this should be very doable, but to have any level of interactivity you'll probably be better off with option #2.

Comment: I am having click function on the chart data point so ,its easy out of the box with slate, but if i use code sandbox, i want to be able to select the data point and show detailed view in a pop up container. 
How to do that in code sandbox ?

& which charting libraries you recommend ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with what the charting library options would be. I would search for a gantt-chart-specific library written in vanilla JS. Since you mention that you'd like a pop-up, which will presumably extend beyond the bounds of the chart since it's fairly small, you may run into another issue. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the code sandbox widget sticks your code in an iframe, and if that's the case I don't know how you would have a pop-up extend beyond the bounds of the iframe.

Comment: I was thinking about this a bit more and, with the caveat that I don't know your full situation, what I might do in your situation is render a regular gantt chart but cover it with an absolutely positioned text html widget. I would rig it up so that when a user goes to click on the gantt chart (which would not be clickable since it's covered by the invisible text html element), a "full-screen" pop-up would appear with a larger gantt chart (so all labels are visible). That's probably a different UX than you were going for originally, but with Slate we all have to be creative sometimes :)

Comment: The absolute position might not work as now the chart is inside a flex div for responsiveness and how can i position something absolute or fixed inside a div with a chart  that moves along with the chart so the responsiveness is maintained